# [R]loops for to find the intervals in the graph and use them for the final formula and plot

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, plot, intervals

This is my code:

```
 Y<-V40      # variable of my dataset (includes 0 and 1) 
X<-V18    # other variable of my dataset 
plot(X,Y)
# loops for to find the intervals in the graph and use them for the final formula and plot
for (i in 1: X) {   
   if(X[i]<40){ 
   AN[i]# Here I would like to find the first interval
   AN[i]<- 14       # if x is equal to 40 I would like to first take the interval from 0 to 10 and count the numbers of 0 and 1(dots) that are in the plot 
   AP[i]<-16       # same speech and i count 1 
   N[i]<-AN[i] + AP[i]   #N
   MAX[i]=AP[i] * log(AP[i]/N[i]) + AN[i] *log(AN[i]/N[i]) # formula for entering new data
   print(MAX[i])            
   lines(Y~X,ADD=MAX[i], xlab='CBO', ylab='Fault-Proneness')

   }
   if(X[i]>40)   # otherwise examine the other interval
   {
     AN[i]<- 1     # if x is equal to 40 I would like to first take the interval from 0 to 10 and count the numbers of 0 and 1(dots) that are in the plot 
     AP[i]<-3      # same speech and i count 1 
     N[i]<-AN[i] + AP[i]   #tot
     MAX[i]=AP[i] * log(AP[i]/N[i]) + AN[i] *log(AN[i]/N[i]) # formula for entering new data                                           #print
     print(MAX[i])                         #print
     lines(Y~X,ADD=MAX[i], xlab='CBO', ylab='Fault-Proneness')

   }

}
```

And this is my plot:[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKZ6.jpg)

And these are the directives:[Directives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezpd2.jpg)

And these are the plots: [PlotExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEomn.jpg)

I would like to know if it is possible to count the numbers of 0 and 1 of this graph in a specific interval and find, with the values ​​found, the MAX and add it to the graph.

Comment: I would need a lot, thank you.

Comment: Your code is not very clear .. At the begining, I invite youy to use `<-` instaed of `=` or worse .. also,  do you think R unsderstand `X` as `x` ? And `plot(x,y, type="l", ADD = MAX)` has no meaning for R.  Moreover, your goal is not clear .. if `i`is in `x`, then `x` is never equal to 40 .. And what are the intervals you are looking for ? Could you add a picture of the desired result ?

Comment: I added the new plot and the directives I have to run

Comment: I changed some parameters to make it easier to understand, I do not know how to go on.

Comment: So when you say add the max, what do you mean ? Add a point ? add a line ? And I still don't see how you want to define your intervalls .. You directives doesn't give anything about that ..

Comment: Could you add the algorithm (in pseudo-code for exemple) you are trying to implement ? I can't guess it till now ..

Comment: Yes,I would like a line that changes according to the searched interval

Comment: So, your first intervall is [0,40] ?

Comment: yes exactly it is from 40 to 60

Comment: practically if X <40 enters the first interval otherwise in the second interval

Comment: Then regarding the loops must be extended to the points and not to the intervals. Each point creates two intervals, from which to calculate AP, AN, and N relative to each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't need a loop .. from your first code :

```
x<-c(23,45,65,46,86,54,78,65,4,3,23,43,65,21,34)       
y<-c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0)
plot(x,y)

xPos1 <- sum(y[x<=40]==1)
xNeg1 <- sum(y[x<=40]==0)

xPos2 <- sum(y[x>40]==1)
xNeg2 <- sum(y[x>40]==0)

NumebrTot1 <- xPos1+xNeg1 
NumebrTot2 <- xPos2+xNeg2
Max1 <- xPos1 * log(xPos1/NumebrTot1) + xNeg1 *log(xNeg1/NumebrTot1)
Max2 <- xPos2 * log(xPos2/NumebrTot2) + xNeg2 *log(xNeg2/NumebrTot2)
```

And then, I don't see exactly what to plot, beacause, by construction, the max value will be negative ...

Comment: You are wonderful, thank you!
it's true for the chart being negative it's difficult to calculate them ...

Comment: If they were positive, how could they be added to plot?